# How to change the format of array from Laravel Controller to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel

How to change the format of array from Laravel Controller to Javascript

```
 $data = DB::table('courses')
        ->selectRaw('courses.course_code,COUNT(student_applicants.status) as total')
        ->leftJoin('student_applicants', function ($join) {
            $join->on('courses.id', '=', 'student_applicants.course_id')
                ->where('student_applicants.status', '=', 1)
                ->where('student_applicants.award_applied', '=', 1);
        })
        ->groupBy('courses.course_code')
        ->pluck('total', 'c.course_code');

        return view('admin.dashboard', ['data' => $data]);
```

I want to achieve this format

```js
[
  "BSA",
  0
], 
[
  "BSBA-HR",
  0
],
```

This is what I get in javascript and Laravel right now

[image: my javascript]

[image: laravel]

Comment: remove the `pluck`?

Comment: when I remove the pluck and replace it to ->get(), this is the outcome [{"course_code":"BSA","total":0},{"course_code":"BSBA-HR","total":0}

Comment: do you know how to hide 'course_code' and 'total'?

Comment: You can achieve that with `array_values()`, but I wonder why you would like to remove the indexes from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You want an array of arrays with single couple of key and value, if i understood right.

Try this one.

```
$dataMapped = $data->map(function($k,$v){
    return [$k => $v];
});
return view('admin.dashboard', ['data' => $dataMapped]);
```

Comment: Thank you for effort, but I already fix it, I just tweak it in JavaScript and it solved my problem.